# TB18DC connectivity problems

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers, mouse, dell-precision

I have a DELL TB18DC docking station connected to my DELL laptop and everything seems to be working fine except for my USB connected mouse which is currently failing to work as it should. Problem is that it lags ... just like if it loses its connection for a split second which is very annoying.

Currently I have tried reinstalling all the related drivers and also updated the drivers, connected a different mouse (both of the mice are working fine when connected to my laptop itself). The problem still persists. I don't seem to get any answers from DELL and therefor I am trying to find them here.

How do I fix the problem?

Comment: I have the same dock on my Precision 3520. Do you have Dell SupportAssist installed? And if so, has it identified any updates to install?

Comment: OK, then via the Dell support page there's a web-based system scan you can run which doesn't depend on SupportAssist being installed. Using that, does it suggest any updates?

Comment: The issue persists after updating

Comment: Have you tried one of the other USB ports on the dock?

Comment: yes ofcourse I have

Comment: I have the same issue with the Dell TB18DC and Dell Precision 7530. I tried so many things, and it's not working. Quite frustrating. The old mechanical docs used to work correctly.

I have found this page a bit useful: https://www.dell.com/support/article/nl/nl/nlbsdt1/sln303581/thunderbolt-dock-tb16-or-tb18dc-10-to-15-second-delay-initializing-connected-devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION ----->

In BIOS:
Under System Configuration\USB Powershare 
Disable USB Powershare.
Under Performance\C-States Control
Disable C-States

EDIT:
STOPPED CHARGING AND FUNCTIONING COMPLETELY
DO NOT BUY THESE THINGS

Comment: I agree do not buy!

Answer (score 0):

Updating the firmware of the dock helped my issues partially.

Here's a thread on how to do it.
https://www.dell.com/community/Precision-Mobile-Workstations/TB18DC-Driver-Update-Not-Easy-to-Find-so-here-it-is/m-p/6210686#M884

Although, I don't like this dock, mainly because of the constant fan noise.